# Batch shape in Keras Custom layer call method

Tags: python, keras, theano

I'm trying to create an implementation of an RBF layer.

Here is the build method:

```
def build(self, input_shape):

    self.centers = self.add_weight(name='centers',
                                   shape=(self.output_dim, input_shape[1]),
                                   initializer=self.initializer,
                                   trainable=True)
    self.betas = self.add_weight(name='betas',
                                 shape=(self.output_dim,),
                                 initializer=Constant(value=self.init_betas),
                                 trainable=True)

    super(RBFLayer, self).build(input_shape)
```

Here is the call:

```
def call(self, x):
    sub = self.centers - x  # centers shape (400, 11970), x shape (100, 11970)
    sqr = sub * sub
    rbf = K.exp(-self.betas * K.sum(sqr, axis=1))
    return rbf  # must have size (100, 400)
```

Input size is 11970

Layer size is 400

Batch size is 100

My problem is that I expected **x**  variable in the call method to be of shape (None, 11970), so that I could subtract it from **self.centers** which is (400, 11970) with broadcasting.

But I'm getting **x** of shape (100, 11970), hence I'm getting a batch at once. And now I need to somehow do 100 subtractions to obtain shape (100, 400, 11970). Then square and sum in the input direction to reduce it to (100, 400) shape.

Could someone advise how to do it?

Comment: Tensor `x` has shape `(batch_size, input_dim)`. Tensor `self.centers` has shape `(output_dim, input_dim)`. Broadcasting won't occur here, because there is a mismatch between `batch_size=100` and `output_dim=400`. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: For the beginning suppose 'batch size' is 1. Input_dim is 11970
'self.centers' is 400 rows and 11970 colums
Now I want to subtract x from centers with broadcasting , so that the x is repeatedly subtracted from every row.

When we have a batch size like 100. I kinda need 'batch_size' copies  of 'self.centers', and then subtract from each copy a sigle batch element with broadcasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood what you want to do. Expand the dimensionality of `self.centers` and `x` as follows and then implicit broadcasting will occur:

```
def call(self, x):
    centers = self.centers[None, :, :]  # Shape=(1, 400, 11970)
    x = x[:, None, :]  # Shape=(100, 1, 11970)
    sub = centers - x  # Shape=(100, 400, 11970)
    sqr = sub * sub
    rbf = K.exp(-self.betas * K.sum(sqr, axis=-1))
    return rbf  # Shape=(100, 400)
```

Note: not tested.

Comment: Thanks, it did work.
Unfortunatelly tensor of size 100,400,11970 does not fit my old GPU memory :-)
Had to reduce batch size to 12